# Dibujar las valores de una dataframe multiindex con Dash

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dash

Tengo un marco de datos multiíndice que me gustaría trazar con Dash:

```
                            claimed_benefit perceived_benefit
My Burberry Je me sens bien     0           0.000000
            romantique          0           0.000000
            convient bien moi   0           0.000000
            féminin             0           0.033898
            sensuelle / sexy    0           0.000000
... ... ... ...
The Beat    harsh / agressif    0           0.000000
            boisé               0           0.000000
            écœurant            0           0.000000
            strength1           0           0.000000
            marron              0           0.000000
```

Y me gustaria hacer un grafico con Dash que seria como lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no sé como obtener las filas anadidas de un marco de datos para crear los diagramas de barras. En efecto soy capaz obtener los datos que quiero dibujar:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv("cb_pb.csv", index_col=0)
>>> df.iloc[3]['perceived_benefit']
0.03389830508474576
>>> df['Unnamed: 1'][0]
'je me sens bien'
```

Pero no soy capaz de utilisarlas en Dash:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Run this app with `python app.py` and
# visit http://127.0.0.1:8050/ in your web browser.

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

df = pd.read_csv("cb_pb.csv", index_col=0)

print(df.head())

trace1 = go.Bar(x=df['Unnamed: 1'][0], y=df.iloc[3]['claimed_benefit'], name='Claimed')
trace2 = go.Bar(x=df['Unnamed: 1'][0], y=df.iloc[3]['perceived_benefit'], name='Perceived')
# trace3 = go.Bar(x=df.index, y=df[('claimed_benefit', 'presented')], name='Presented')
# trace4 = go.Bar(x=df.index, y=df[('claimed_benefit', 'won')], name='Won')

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Scores of perfumes over claimed attributes'),
    html.Div(children='''National Sales Funnel Report.'''),
    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [trace1],
            'layout':
            go.Layout(title='Order Status by Customer', barmode='stack')
        })
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Me devuelve:

```
(venv) C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass>python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
    trace1 = go.Bar(x=df['Unnamed: 1'][0], y=df.iloc[3]['perceived_benefit'], name='Declined')
  File "C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass\venv\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\_bar.py", line 3085, in __init__
    self["x"] = _v
  File "C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass\venv\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py", line 4804, in __setitem__
    self._set_prop(prop, value)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass\venv\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py", line 5148, in _set_prop
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass\venv\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py", line 5143, in _set_prop
    val = validator.validate_coerce(val)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass\venv\lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py", line 393, in validate_coerce
    self.raise_invalid_val(v)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass\venv\lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py", line 287, in raise_invalid_val
    valid_clr_desc=self.description(),
ValueError:
    Invalid value of type 'builtins.str' received for the 'x' property of bar
        Received value: 'je me sens bien'

    The 'x' property is an array that may be specified as a tuple,
    list, numpy array, or pandas Series
```

Comment: Un `KeyError` en `Pandas` significa que la columna que estás intentando acceder no existe. En este caso te dice que cuando vas a crear el gráfico con `go.Bar()` la columna `'My Burberry - Eau de Parfum'` no existe.

Comment: @RubialesAlberto En efecto , olvidé descargar la primera columna del mio csv como el index